# When would one use malloc over zmalloc?

Tags: c, malloc, zmalloc

There is precious little information online or on stackoverflow with regards to a function I recently encountered called `zmalloc`. (In fact, this is only the 3rd `zmalloc`-tagged question on SO).

I gleaned the following:

- zmalloc automatically keeps track of, and frees unfreed memory, similar to C++ smart pointers.
- zmalloc apparently enables some metrics, at least in [the case of the redis source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/dPRdpowqJsY).

So my questions are:

1. What flexibility does one lose, then, in using zmalloc over malloc? i.e. what benefits do malloc continue to offer that zmalloc does not?
2. Is zmalloc non-standard in C11? Is this a custom-built function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like zmalloc is part of the redis-tools (https://github.com/antirez/redis-tools). redis is a kind of database which keeps stuff in memory (http://redis.io/).

Typically malloc replacements are developed because some target systems do not provide a suitable malloc, or because the caller needs extra functionality. I think zmalloc is a pretty simple wrapper of the system malloc/free, just keeping track of the overall memory allocated. No automatic free involved. The post you pointed to also explains the need: The database can be configured to not use more than some amount of memory and thus needs to keep track of the overall consumption.

Comment: Thanks Peter, according to the stackoverflow tag description, it auto-frees... would you say the tag is wrong, then?

Comment: Yes, the tag wiki is wrong. I already proposed an edit to fix it. As a sidenote, `zmalloc()` is not the best written code I've seen so far, it adds significantly more overhead than necessary. Of course, that overhead is dwarfed by the overhead of `malloc()` itself, but still, code like that should be written by people who know how to optimize...

Comment: @cmaster: What specifically caught your eye being suboptimal?

Comment: @PeterSchneider a) Using an `if` to perform rounding up to a power of two within the main execution path instead of just doing `rounded = (unrounded + n-1) & ~(n-1);`. The `if` flushes the entire pipeline whenever it is mispredicted, the arithmetic is just two simple instructions. b) Using rounding at all. It is not necessary, it just wastes time. c) Performing the size correction in `zrealloc()` in two steps instead of one. d) The entirely pointless `flush()` on `stderr`, which is already guaranteed by the standard to be unbuffered. Of course, that flush is never executed anyway, but still...

Comment: @cmaster did you ever mention this to antirez?